# Can't create Comparer

Tags: .net, icomparer

I have a class

```
public class PAUserAllowedTimesModel
{
    public List<AllowedTime> Times { get; set; }
    public List<AllowedTime> BusyTimes { get; set; }
    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
    public int DateID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of object of this class:

```
List<PAUserAllowedTimesModel> model = ...
```

I want to sort this collection by SelectedDate. I try:

```
public class PAUserAllowedTimesModelComparer : IComparer<ITW2012Mobile.ViewModels.PAUserAllowedTimesModel>
{
    public int Compare(ViewModels.PAUserAllowedTimesModel x, ViewModels.PAUserAllowedTimesModel y)
    {
        if (x.SelectedDate > y.SelectedDate)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

and then

```
model.Sort(new PAUserAllowedTimesModelComparer());
```

but it just mix elements, not sort. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comparer will *never* return -1, so it's violating the `Compare` contract...

Fortunately you can make it much simpler anyway:

```
public int Compare(ViewModels.PAUserAllowedTimesModel x, 
                   ViewModels.PAUserAllowedTimesModel y)
{
    // Possibly reverse this, depending on what you're trying to do
    return x.SelectedDate.CompareTo(y.SelectedDate);
}
```

Or using LINQ:

```
model = model.OrderBy(x => x.SelectedDate).ToList();
```

Note that this doesn't do an *in-place* sort, unlike `List<T>.Sort`.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation of `IComparer` is wrong. You need to return 0 if the elements are **equal**, 1 if `x > y` and -1 if `y > x` or vice versa, depending on whether you want to sort descending or ascending.